# Bing Maps v8 - heatMap.setLocation is not a function

Tags: bing, bing-api, bing-maps

I am trying the new Bing Maps v8 using HeatMapLayer Class. The docs describes a setLocation method, as link below:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt712811.aspx

I created an example based on Bing Maps Interactive SDK (http://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdk/mapcontrol/isdk#defaultHeatMap+JS).

But an error occurs when I run my script:

**ERROR: heatMap.setLocation is not a function**

Can someone help me, please?

```
var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'), {
    credentials: 'Your Bing Maps Key',
    center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(39.393486, -98.100769),
    zoom: 3
});

Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.HeatMap', function () {
    // Creating sample Pushpin data within map view
    var mapDiv = map.getRootElement();
    var locations = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        locations.push(map.tryPixelToLocation(new Microsoft.Maps.Point(mapDiv.clientWidth * Math.random(), mapDiv.clientHeight * Math.random()), Microsoft.Maps.PixelReference.control));
    }
    var heatMap = new Microsoft.Maps.HeatMapLayer();
    heatMap.setLocation(locations); // error line
    map.layers.insert(heatMap);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a typo in the documentation, should be setLocations. Most devs simply pass the array of locations into the constructor when creating the heatmap, likely the reason why this wasn't noticed sooner. Or they use the TypeScript definitions when developing which has the correct function name.

I've had the documentation updated to fix this typo. It will likely take 15 minutes for the MSDN site to update. Thanks for reporting.